# Linking a new child with its parent when adding a new child

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, parent-child

I have a `customer` model that has_many `events` When I go to the customer show page, I have links to all of the `events` that are owned by `customer`. I want to add a "New event for this customer" link. Right now, I'm doing that with `<%= link_to "New Event for this Customer", new_event_path %>` but when I follow that link, I have to manually enter in the customer's id number. How can I automate this so that when I click "Add new event for this customer" rails knows that I'm adding a new event for that particular customer instead of having to put in the customer_id myself?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are looking for is called `nested resources`, here's a [good introduction](http://weblog.jamisbuck.org/2007/2/5/nesting-resources).

For this specific case you should declare your routes like these:

```
map.resources :customers do |customers|
   customers.resources :events
end
```

The above declaration would allow you to define routes like:

```
new_customer_event_url(@customer.id)
=> customers/:customer_id/events/new
```

And in your specific case:

```
<%= link_to "New Event for this Customer", new_customer_event_path(@customer) %>
```

Comment: This worked perfectly, thank you. My next question is once I'm at the child, how do I link back to its parent show page?

Comment: You'll be able to define the following link, `link_to "Customer", customer_path(@customer)` assuming you are defining `@customer` in your controller. Maybe `def find_customer; @customer = Customer.find(params[:customer_id]); end;`

Comment: PD, If you wish to view all the generated routes for `customers` you can always run `rake routes | grep customer` that helps a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Add the customer id to the link as parameter `<%= link_to "New Event for this Customer", new_event_path, {:cust_id => customer.id} %>` and in the form, set this as a hidden param for event object. Your model will automatically be populated with the customer id.